# Symfony custom config cascade

Tags: php, symfony1

In Symfony 1.4, is it possible for one to define a custom config file (e.g. my_config.yml) that allows cascading; for instance, having a global custom config file and a module level analogue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Define a config handler in `config_handlers.yml`. It'll probably look like:

```
config/my_config.yml:
  class: myConfigHandler
```

Write your config handler. You can look at many of the other config handlers in `lib/config` for examples. You'll likely want to extend `sfYamlConfigHandler`.

To access your config values:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfigCache()->checkConfig('/config/my_config.yml');
```

Comment: is it a must to define a custom config handler, or is it sometimes ok to use one of the handlers defined in the symfony lib directory? (e.g. sfDefineEnvironmentConfigHandler.class.php)